# "jekyll 3.6.2 | Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen" after Firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, rubygems, jekyll

I have a [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) blog hosted with Firebase. Using [RubyInstaller for Windows](https://rubyinstaller.org/) - sometimes after deploying to Firebase, it's no longer possible to build the jekyll website due `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen`

It seems this just randomly occurs after working some hours, see log below (just after a successful build and deploy):

```
C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>jekyll build
Configuration file: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog
       Destination: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.598 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.

C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>firebase deploy
1

=== Deploying to 'Liukang-blog'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing _site directory for upload...
+  hosting: 9 files uploaded successfully

+  Deploy complete!

C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>jekyll build
Configuration file: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog
       Destination: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.573 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.

C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>firebase deploy
1

=== Deploying to 'Liukang-blog'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing _site directory for upload...
+  hosting: 9 files uploaded successfully

+  Deploy complete!

C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>jekyll build
Configuration file: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/BLOG/liukang_blog
       Destination: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/BLOG/liukang_blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.581 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.

C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>firebase deploy
1

=== Deploying to 'Liukang-blog'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing _site directory for upload...
+  hosting: 9 files uploaded successfully

+  Deploy complete!

C:\Users\Liukang\Google Drive\MY-BLOG\liukang_blog>jekyll build
Configuration file: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog
       Destination: C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Liukang/Google Drive/MY-BLOG/liukang_blog/firebase-debug.log
```

I can't open *firebase-debug.log* or delete it. I can "solve" the problem by shutting down the computer, which is frustrating.

**Edit:** Exiting the terminal also seems to work.

Is this caused by not having correct file permission - if so, how do I setup the correct permission, so this doesn't happen again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the permissions of the files/folders inside your MY-BLOG by directing it to be owned by your user. Just go to My-BLOG folder and try the following command for taking the ownership of all the files and folders in windows.

```
takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y
takeown /F <filename>
```

To know more about permisisions in windows http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/taking-ownership-file-or-folder-command-line